# FTP connection trouble between two servers

Tags: networking, firewall, ftp

I am facing a problem with the FTP connectivity between two Windows servers. Both servers are present in two different networks behind their respective firewalls. I have opened the port 21 in both firewalls to allow FTP connectivity. I tried to do the telnet in both directions and it is working.

Once telnet worked fine, I added and enabled FTP service in the FTP server and trying to pull the files from another (client) server. Unfortunately it is not working for me and getting 'Connection Timed Out' error. I also tried directly connecting from Winscp and same error (Connection Timed Out) I am getting.

I am really in trouble as I spent one week in all these activities and still no luck. Can someone please help here.

```
2020-02-11 17:10:29 10.211.74.3 - 10.232.163.75 21 ControlChannelOpened - - 0 0 cd8cf557-d62d-4076-8d35-7e4ff9d8ff5b - 
2020-02-11 17:10:29 10.211.74.3 - 10.232.163.75 21 USER anonymous 331 0 0 cd8cf557-d62d-4076-8d35-7e4ff9d8ff5b - 
2020-02-11 17:10:29 10.211.74.3 - 10.232.163.75 21 PASS a@a.com 230 0 0 cd8cf557-d62d-4076-8d35-7e4ff9d8ff5b / 
2020-02-11 17:10:29 10.211.74.3 - 10.232.163.75 21 opts utf8+on 200 0 0 cd8cf557-d62d-4076-8d35-7e4ff9d8ff5b - 
2020-02-11 17:10:29 10.211.74.3 - 10.232.163.75 21 syst - 215 0 0 cd8cf557-d62d-4076-8d35-7e4ff9d8ff5b - 
2020-02-11 17:10:29 10.211.74.3 - 10.232.163.75 21 site help 214 0 0 cd8cf557-d62d-4076-8d35-7e4ff9d8ff5b - 
2020-02-11 17:10:29 10.211.74.3 - 10.232.163.75 21 PWD - 257 0 0 cd8cf557-d62d-4076-8d35-7e4ff9d8ff5b - 
2020-02-11 17:10:29 10.211.74.3 - 10.232.163.75 21 TYPE A 200 0 0 cd8cf557-d62d-4076-8d35-7e4ff9d8ff5b - 
2020-02-11 17:10:29 10.211.74.3 - 10.232.163.75 21 PASV - 227 0 0 cd8cf557-d62d-4076-8d35-7e4ff9d8ff5b - 
2020-02-11 17:11:09 - - 10.232.163.75 58684 DataChannelClosed - - 258 15 cd8cf557-d62d-4076-8d35-7e4ff9d8ff5b -
```

Comment: Please [edit] and format the error message so it is readable.

Comment: I think you should perhaps trying opening up TCP port `20` in addition to `21` to ensure both 'data' and 'control' channels are allowed thru. You also might need to understand the "passive" port range your "connecting" FTP server uses for the one you are connecting to for allowing those thru. I believe you are connecting `PASV` or passive per the logs you removed rather than reformatting for easier readability. It might also be helpful to put your FTP server versions, etc. in your question. Confirm you can connect to both server with WinSCP and send data on respective internal networks too.

Comment: What server systems are you using and how are those configured? This is important to understand too in your troubleshooting. Knowing this will help you understand how you may need to configure your network for example with firewall and routers across the hops or networks.

Comment: FTP is not designed to work well with firewalls and/or NAT routing. In general, active mode FTP will (mostly) tolerate firewalls on server side, and passive mode will (mostly) tolerate firewalls on client side. If you have firewalls on both sides (as you do), things get messy. Can you switch to a more modern protocol?

Comment: I checked from WinScp and FTP connection is happening. Issues is when WinScp try listing the FTP server directories and it is getting timed out.

Comment: @RadhaGupta FTP uses multiple TCP connections; the control connection connection (used for e.g. sending commands) will work fine through firewalls, but the data connection (for file contents, directory listings, etc) is problematic. That's why directory listings are timing out. Again, can you switch to a more modern protocol? BTW, there are other reasons to ditch FTP, such as the fact that it exposes your password in plaintext on the network.

Answer (score 0):

Just to update, finally I have resolved the issue.

I switched to FTPS approach for security purpose but it did not resolve the problem. After going number of articles on FTPS communication, I got to know that the issue may get resolved by opening a data channel port range on the client server's network firewall. My network team helped to me open a data channel port range and it worked.

Thank you all.